# Reset git settings

Tags: git

When I try downloading [this](https://git01.codeplex.com/casablanca) git repo I keep getting `error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200` and I think this is because I messed up some settings (i was playing about with `--config` and `--bare` today)

Is there a way how I can reset my git configuration to the factory settings?

If it helps I am on a Mac.

Comment: Nothing to do with you or any settings you have changed. Using `--bare` has nothing to do with any settings, and using `--config` only affects the repository you're working in unless you've also used `--global`.

Comment: I did use `--global`

Comment: Then, as I answered, delete `~/.gitconfig`. However, this will not change anything, you still will not be able to clone that repository.

Comment: Why cant I clone it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Git settings are stored in `~/.gitconfig`. Just delete that file.

Comment: You could also just open the file and only delete the things you don't need.

Comment: @AlexH That wasn't the question. "How to reset to factory settings".